# Link wrapping blocks breaks element

Tags: css

I want to create an icon that looks like a circle with a "plus" icon inside and right below it a descriptive `p` tag.

For I reason I cannot figure out doing this completely breaks the whole block. What am I doing wrong?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/82060cme/)

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="follow-single">
    <div class="follow-wrapper">
        <a class="follow" id="@follow_4" rel="nofollow" data-method="put" href="/jessie/follow">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
            <p class="title">Unfollow</p>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
follow-single {
    max-width: 360px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
.follow-single .follow-wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}
.follow-single .follow-wrapper .follow {
    color: #3c763d;
    background-color: #dff0d8;
    border: 1px solid #d6e9c6;
    padding: 10px 17px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.follow-single .follow-wrapper a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.follow-single .follow-wrapper .title {
    font-size: 12px;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the display on the achor tag to be inline-block.

```
.follow {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/82060cme/3/)

Additionally, an unrelated to the original question, your definition of `follow-single` is missing a leading dot character: `.follow-single`